# How to refresh activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, refresh, android-videoview

I have an android application that pulls a list of videos stored in an sd-card and plays them.

When I click on the play button, a separate activity starts with VideoView, and I need to refresh the main activity that called the VideoView activity to play the video. What I need is that when the video is finished or the user clicks the back button, I want the activity to be refreshed. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override onResume() and update your activity there. How you update it depends on what kind of activity it is and what needs updating. If you're using an ArrayAdapter in a ListActivity, for instance, you can call `getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()` after updating the data.

Comment: Actually Sir, I just want to refresh the whole Activity in the same way as it is done when we change the orientation.. is there any way? Instead of updating, I want the whole Activity to refresh or restart..

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but you can use this code: `startActivity(getIntent()); finish();`. It's pretty wasteful, and you would probably be better off repeating the logic of `onCreate`, including a new call to `setContentView`.

Comment: I would instead suggest moving the code you wish to be executed each time the activity is resumed into `onResume()`. If you only want it to run when returning from the video activity, refactor the code into a method and call it both from `onCreate()` and `onActivityResult()`. When invoking the intent to the video activity, do so via `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 2):

I posted this on another link, try this:

```
finish();startActivity(getIntent());
```

OR

```
// Refresh main activity upon close of dialog box
Intent refresh =new Intent(this, ActivityWeAreIn.class);
startActivity(refresh);
```

Note: this also works with Activity objects or from Fragments using getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Implement onResume() see [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
public void onResume(Bundle s) {
       this.onCreate(s);
}
```

Comment: no sir. It didn't work. I need to refresh the activity from scratch just like the application does when the orientation changes..